# C# Text formatting - Align doesn't work correct

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'd like to format some texts to have same width. I'd tried to use String.Format and Interpolated Strings but I'm not successful. I give an example:

I have a listbox and I want to insert some formatted text.

```
listBox1.Items.Add($"{"Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter",-60}{"Sample"}");
listBox1.Items.Add($"{"Device Bluetooth",-60}{"Sample"}");
```

I'd expected that the text will be aligned under each other because I set for every text 60 characters length but It doesn't work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Maybe I misunderstand how text formatting works. Or doesn't it work correct because every char has different width?

Comment: If that works at all at least you'll need  to use a fixed-width font like Consolas or Courier.

Comment: Yes, now I tried it and it works correct if I use a fixed-width font like Consolas. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to have columns look at a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on whether the font is **monospaced** - if it is, strings' lengths look equal.

[monospaced strings' lengths look equal](https://image.prntscr.com/image/49RSMgl7SVaVVFgrJcAjaQ.png)